# Buffer data for bulk insertion

Tags: logging, rabbitmq, clickhouse

Everytime a request is made on my website some data about that event is recorded into database(Yandex ClickHouse). ClickHouse works dramatically faster if the inserts are being done in bulks of size of at least 1000 records. On every request i want to send the data to another computer that is going to store the data and then flush it to the database when the buffer reaches some sizes, say 1000. I'm considering using RabbitMQ for message passing/bufferizing, but i`m not sure that it's the right tool. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

[Buffer](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/buffer/) table engine created directly for this purpose.
Shortly, you create table with this type of engine and write to this table/read from this table.
All records would be buffered in RAM and automatically flushed to source table according to settings.

Answer (score 1):

We chose to let nginx send access logs in json format to a syslog server(syslog-ng) syslog-ng can use an external application. and can STDIN data into the application. so we wrote a golang utility to bulk insert into clickhouse.

this worked very well for us.

Ofcrouse you could also write a golang tool to consume from rabbitmq and bulk insert into clickhouse.

at peak we are doing 140 k messages per second so i wrote it that golang does one query per second. so it auto scale up and down depending on the volume of messages per second.

https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-destinations-program.html

http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html

Answer (score 0):

yep, RabbitMQ it's a right tool for your usecase
but also you can try use buffer table engine
https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/table_engines/buffer.html

Answer (score 0):

We have been using clickhouse for collecting data from a good number of node servers at about 300k qps and have been using [Buffer tables](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/buffer/) to deal with that "too many parts" issue. Some limitations we have been experienced when using Buffer tables. Most of all, it is more likely to cause a single point of failure: high load average, hard to control memory consumption,  lost data when the process hung.

Our front servers are written in Nodejs, so we made a distributed buffer layer for each server node, called [clickhouse-cargo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clickhouse-cargo).

Now the data flow goes like this:
Servers -> clickhouse-cargo -> Buffer tables -> Real Clickhouse tables

This implementation works steadily. No data loss, low load average, requires much less memory on the Clickhouse servers and makes the whole thing running much cheaper.

Comment: If you use clickhouse-cargo, then you can directly insert the batch of data into Real Clickhouse tables. We don't want to write again to Buffer table. Correct?